# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2014 (gravatar hats)?

Tags: discussion

The year is drawing to a close and Stack Exchange is planning another Winter Bash. We, as a community, get to decide if we'd like to participate in this event.

This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

We have until December 1 to decide. If we do not make a decision by then, we are opt'd IN by default.

Does Video Production.SE want to gather hats this winter?

Answer (score 3):

Don't be a hater... be a hatter!  Bring on the Hats!!!

Answer (score 0):

You hatters are mad. Nobody likes hats; they scratch and ruin houses with their smell. Down with the hats. May our mullets and bald spots roam free.

<sub>Actually, I don't really care if people want the hats or not. I usually ignore them, but thought someone should take the other road.</sub>

Comment: I almost want to vote this up just for sticking with the theme of silly hat related jokes.

Answer (score 0):

Winter? That's six months away. Or are you getting ready early for when Winter starts—as it always does around here—in June.

Comment: I'm guessing "White Christmas" isn't a popular song around you then...  You should contact SE though and let them know they are a bunch of insensitive clods. ;)

Comment: Yep, Christmas around here usually means temperatures in the high 30s and 40s (celsius that is). You still want to wear a hat, but just to stop yourself getting sunburned.

Comment: so what you are saying is that you much prefer tan Christmas...